# JqGrid cerrar dialogo al guardar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Hola tengo el problema de que no se como indicar a mi dialogo de Jquery que se cierre al guardar, uso el dialogo de editar de jquery de la siguiente manera.

```
        ondblClickRow: function(rowid){
         jQuery(this).jqGrid('editGridRow',rowid);
         },
```

Que lo que hace es que al darle doble click sobre la fila se abre el dialogo de Jquery con los input que tienen la opción de editable:true y manda todos los datos cuando le doy guardar y ya me hace todo perfecto, pero cuando le doy guardar y termina, no se cierra el dialogo y no se como hacerle estaba leyendo que tiene esta propiedad: closeAfterEdit:true pero no se como indicarsela, la coloque en el código donde creo mi Grid pero no funciono.

Aquí mi codigo completo

```
  jQuery("#tbl_mat_puesto").jqGrid({
    url:"select_mat_puesto.php?id_puesto="+id,
    datatype: 'json',
    type:'POST',
    colNames:['ID','Puesto','Clase','Insumo','Clave','Cantidad','UMED','PRECIO HIST'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id',align:'left',key:true,width:80,hidden:false},
        {name:'puesto_m',index:'puesto_m',align:'left',width:50},
        {name:'clase_m',index:'clase_m',align:'left',width:80,search:true},
        {name:'insumo_m',index:'insumo_m',align:'left',width:50},
        {name:'clave_m',index:'clave_m',align:'left',sortable:true,editable:false,width:80,search:true},
        {name:'cantidad',index:'cantidad',align:'right',sortable:true,editable:false,width:10,search:true,editable:true},
        {name:'umed',index:'umed',align:'left',sortable:true,editable:false,width:15,search:true},
        {name:'precio_hist',index:'precio_hist',align:'right',sortable:true,editable:false,width:20,search:false}
    ],
    rownumbers:true,
    rowNum:100,
    rowList:[100,200,500,1000],
    toppager:true,
    sortname:'',
    sortorder:'asc',
    viewrecords:true,
    caption:'Materiales por puesto',
    height: 250,
    width: 950,
    rownumbers: true,
    multiselect:false,
    loadonce: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    closeAfterEdit:true, 
    editurl:'aumenta_cantidad.php?id_puesto='+id,
    loadComplete:function(){
        // $('.infoidse').parents('td').css('background-color','rgba(222,234,255,1);');
    },
    afterInsertRow: function (){
    },
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid){
      jQuery(this).jqGrid('editGridRow',rowid);
    },

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que a tu jqGrid le falta un método `afterSubmit`

La impronta de `afterSubmit` es ([según la wiki de jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing&s[]=aftersubmit))

```
afterSubmit : function(response, postdata) 
{ 
… 
return [success,message,new_id] 
}
```

Así que declarando esa opción:

```
jQuery("#tbl_mat_puesto").jqGrid({
    ...
    afterInsertRow: function (){
    },
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid){
      jQuery(this).jqGrid('editGridRow',rowid);
    },
    afterSubmit : function(response, postdata) {
      alert('se envió la data');
    }

});
```

puedes ejecutar acciones a tu gusto. Por ejemplo, puedes gatillar manualmente el cierre del diálogo, ya sea llamando a un método interno de jqGrid o incluso gatillando a mano el método `click` en el botón de cerrar (que sería la manera menos elegante de hacerlo).

**EDIT**: Esta segunda posibilidad me tinca más adecuada.

Hay otra posibilidad, y es que las opciones para editar una celda o fila no deban adosarse al objeto jqGrid principal, sino al método `editGridRow`

En otras palabras, debieras poner

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid){
   jQuery(this).jqGrid('editGridRow',rowid,{
         closeAfterEdit:true
   });
},
```

Comment: Muchas gracias esto ulltimo es lo que andaba buscando, ya lo habia escondido con la función Click pero no era muy conveniente. Gracias.